# Java Base64 decode results differs unexpectedly

Tags: java, base64

I have a transparent, 1x1 GIF file with the following data:

```
$ xxd pixel.gif
00000000: 4749 4638 3961 0100 0100 f000 0000 0000  GIF89a..........
00000010: 0000 0021 f904 0100 0000 002c 0000 0000  ...!.......,....
00000020: 0100 0100 0002 0244 0100 3b              .......D..;
```

The Base64 encoded data for this file is as follows:

```
$ openssl base64 -in pixel.gif
R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==
```

If I decode this string, I get the following correct output:

```
$ echo 'R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==' | openssl base64 -d | xxd
00000000: 4749 4638 3961 0100 0100 f000 0000 0000  GIF89a..........
00000010: 0000 0021 f904 0100 0000 002c 0000 0000  ...!.......,....
00000020: 0100 0100 0002 0244 0100 3b
```

When trying to decode this string in Java, I get unexpected results back. Consider this example Java program:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.util.Base64;

public class Decode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
            String line = reader.readLine();

            //System.out.println(line.getBytes());
            byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(line.getBytes());
            System.out.print(new String(data, 0, data.length, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException reading System.in");
        }
    }
}
```

When I pipe the encoded string to this program, I get the following results

```
$ echo 'R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==' | java Decode | xxd
00000000: 4749 4638 3961 0100 0100 efbf bd00 0000  GIF89a..........
00000010: 0000 0000 0021 efbf bd04 0100 0000 002c  .....!.........,
00000020: 0000 0000 0100 0100 0002 0244 0100 3b    ...........D..
```

I can see at the 11th byte the expected output of `0xf0` changes to `0xef`. The entire binary string is now 47 bytes long instead of 43 bytes long. Why is this happening with Java?

Comment: If you try to encode binary data in UTF-8 you'll get nasty surprises. (EDIT: removed the part about printing to the console as it's not relevant here)

Comment: Bytes with the 8th bit set as in F0 will be converted to a multi-byte sequence in UTF-8. Do not use String for binary data. You could try `StandardCharsets,ISO_8859_1` to convert it with a bit of luck. But mind, twice the memory is used as char is 2 bytes, containing only 1 byte of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert arbitrary binary data to a UTF-8 string. UTF-8 is a unicode encoding which follows certain rules (e.g. all multibyte sequences must start with 11 or 10 as high-bits, and the first byte of a multibyte sequence tells the decoder how many bytes are contained in this multibyte sequence)

What you really want is to write the byte array directly, not convert it to a String first:

```java
byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(line.getBytes());
System.out.write(data);
```